# Particle decay of the delta + baryon and feynman diagrams

Tags: tikz-feynman

I am using the `tikz-feynman` package to draw Feynman diagrams for an assignment. I am considering the `$\Delta^{+}\to n+\pi^{+}$` process. Using this package and with the code below, I have drawn this diagram:

[image: Drawn diagram]

I would like to know how it would be possible to make each independant line closer to each other, to get a more pretty diagram. Moreover, is there a way to put two brackets at the end, to get something akin to this:

[image: Diagram I want to draw]

I don't know how to share the code without the website trying to compile it, so here is a screenshot of it:

[image: Code]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is important that you add your minimal working example and not a snippet code (screenshot).

Comment: @Sebastiano what do you mean?

Comment: You should put the whole code in TeX.

Comment: @Juian: Copy the code directly from your editor. Then paste it into your question, highlight it, and click the `{}` button at the top of your question. Screenshots of code are not helpful to other users because we want to to copy your code and paste it into our own editor to work on your problem. But most of us are not going to type your code from the screenshot. [See here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) for more information.